# pydantic v2 python validation, how to dump some, not all fields with None value

Tags: python-3.x, validation, pydantic

I have a model with many fields that can have None value.
Pydantic (v2) provides easy way to do two things

- include certain fields only when calling `model_dump` using the `include` argument with a list of fields.
- not to include fields that have a `None` value by setting the `exclude_none` argument to `True`

What is the way to ensure some (but not others) fields are included even though they have the `None` value? If I include both `exclude_none` and `include` arguments, the exclude part wins.

The following unit test will fail

```
import unittest
from pydantic import BaseModel
class A(BaseModel):
    a: str | None

class PydanticIncludeAndExcludedNoneTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """    Shows that `exclude_none` wins over `include` when dumping the pydantic v2 model    """
    def test_simple(self):
        item = A(a=None)
        d = item.model_dump(include={'a'}, exclude_none=True)
        self.assertEqual(d['a'], None)  # add assertion here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_serializer

class A(BaseModel):
    a: str | None
    b: str | None

    @model_serializer(mode="wrap")
    def _serialize(self, handler):
        d = handler(self)
        d['a'] = self.a
        return d


a1 = A(a=None, b=None)

a2 = A(a="strrrr", b=None)


print(a1.model_dump(exclude_none=True))

print(a2.model_dump(exclude_none=True))
```

Output:

```
{'a': None}
{'a': 'strrrr'}
```

Or you can modify it to have the list of mandatory fields as a parameter of model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_serializer

class A(BaseModel):
    a: str | None
    b: str | None
    c: int | None

    _always_serialize_fields: list["str"] = ["a", "c"]

    @model_serializer(mode="wrap")
    def _serialize(self, handler):
        d = handler(self)
        for f in self._always_serialize_fields:
            d[f] = getattr(self, f)
        return d


a1 = A(a=None, b = None, c=None)

a2 = A(a="strrrr", b=None, c=None)


print(a1.model_dump(exclude_none=True))

print(a2.model_dump(exclude_none=True))
```

Output:

```
{'a': None, 'c': None}
{'a': 'strrrr', 'c': None}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is the answer that works. I was hoping to be able to do it at the @field_serializer level. I could not. Not sure why. Thank you. One thing that I changed was having a Set, rather than list of _always_serialize_fields. Set is faster lookup, though for the problem size it is probably totally negligible.